# `summarise_each_()` is deprecated as of dplyr 0.7.0. Please use `across()` instead. Problem with `summarise()` input `..1`

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have this and it works:

```
data %>%
        select_if(function(x) any(is.na(x))) %>% 
        summarise_each(funs(sum(is.na(.))))
```

> Warning message:
> `summarise_each()` is deprecated as of dplyr 0.7.0.
> Please use `across()` instead.

When I change sumarise_each():

```
data %>%
        select_if(function(x) any(is.na(x))) %>% 
        summarise(across(funs(sum(is.na(.)))))
```

This happen:

> Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `..1`.
> x Must subset columns with a valid subscript vector.
> x Subscript has the wrong type `fun_list`.
> ℹ It must be numeric or character.
> ℹ Input `..1` is `across(funs(sum(is.na(.))))`.

I want to update my code with the across function.

Comment: You're likely to get a better response if you provide a reproducible example of the data you're working with and what you want your expected output to look like. The first thing you'll want to look at is the order of arguments that `summarise(across())` is expecting. The first argument to `across` should be the columns you want the function(s) applied to. Without seeing your data or a sense of what you're trying to do it will be hard to advise beyond that. You're trying to select all columns that have at least 1 NA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The across way to do this is:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  summarize(across(where(~any(is.na(.)), ~sum(is.na(.)))) 

starwars %>% 
  summarise(across(where(~any(is.na(.))), ~sum(is.na(.))))

 height  mass hair_color birth_year   sex gender homeworld species
   <int> <int>      <int>      <int> <int>  <int>     <int>   <int>
1      6    28          5         44     4      4        10       4
```

You no longer need `select_if` with `across()`. The `where()` inside `across()` allows you do do a logical check. Then you provide the summarizing function. The `~` notation allows you to do a function that refers back to the data, where the dot refers to the data in eahc column.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I think you're trying to do

```
    library(dplyr)
    df <- data.frame(id=c("001","002"), A = c(0,0), B= c(NA,0), C=c(NA,1))
    df

         id  A  B  C
1        001 0 NA NA
2        002 0  0  1


    df %>%
    select(where(function(x) any(is.na(x)))) %>%
    rowwise %>%
    mutate(sumNA = sum(is.na(c_across(everything()))))

    # A tibble: 2 x 3
    # Rowwise: 
       B      C    sumNA
     <dbl>  <dbl>  <int>
  1    NA    NA     2
  2    0     1      0
```

This selects all columns that contain NA and then adds a new column which shows how many NA's are in each row